# How to resolve reference error "src/environments/environment.ts' is not a module."

Tags: angular, gitignore, environment, api-key

Hi I am trying to implement the solution to hide sensitive Information(for example GOOGLE_API_KEY)

To do this I have created environment.ts file and added to .gitignore section, as I don't want to push to Git but it is available during development in the local box.

Question: How do I make the reference working for import * as environment from '../../environments/environment.test' in different file.

for example: test.ts

Please help me how to overcome this?

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just import only the `environment.ts` is enough. When you `serve` or `build` your project. It'll have a configuration in `angular.json` to look for configuration file and replace it for you.

For more information: [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/build)